# PHP MySQL form values to database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add all the form values to my database, i know how to insert new records, but with the "Image" i would like to upload, i`m stuck.

What would be the simplest way to insert all from values and upload the image and insert the image url in the database?

Form Source:

```
<form action="_eventcreate.php" id="contactform" method="POST">
<p>
<label for="event_name">Event Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="event_name" class="input" value="">
</p><p>
<label for="event_description">Description:</label>
<input type="text" name="event_description" cols="88" rows="6" class="input" value="">
</p><p>
<label for="event_date">Event Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="event_date" class="input" value="">
</p><p>
<label for="event_time">Event Time:</label>
<input type="text" name="event_time" class="input" value="">
</p><p>
<label for="event_cost">Event Cost:</label>
<input type="text" name="event_cost" class="input" value="">
</p><p>
<label for="event_image">Upload Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Event" class="submit">                    
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `<input type="file" name="image"/>` for the upload.

2) In the form tag add: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

3) Use the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) collection to get the info about the uploaded file(s).

4) Use `is_uploaded_file()`, `move_uploaded_file()` to check for the file & move it to its final destination.

5) Make sure you save the file in a directory which is accessible through the web & create a URL for it to be saved in the database.

Check out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: ///////////////////////////////////////// Upload File to Directory
  $uploaddir = '../gallery/';
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
  $event_image=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

chk this url

```
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
```

you will get a better idea on how to do it..

and you can embed your code to insert all the form data with the image name and its other details after cheking that $_FILES has no errors...

Although there are many libraries and framework which manage the internals and you just have to call a function or 2...
like

```
http://pear.php.net/HTTP_Upload
```

Answer (score 0):

This link may be useful:
[PHP File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)
Use $_FILES["file"]["name"] to insert to "image" field in your DB table

Answer (score 0):

or even better you can try jquery file uploaders available in amplitude on net like valium-file-uploader